# SQL Server : Offset Rows Fetch Next with parent child relationshiops

Tags: .net, sql-server

We currently use paged grids for displaying some of our data.  In order to accomplish paging, we pass in a start and count parameter into our data function for the OFFSET and FETCH NEXT portions of our query.

In general, this works except in the case of when we have a one-> many relationship in our data.  In these instances, we get (as expected) duplicate parent rows for each of the child properties.  Using Dapper, we can handle merging this data into the object appropriately.

The issue however is that the OFFSET and FETCH NEXT also takes these child rows into account.  If we want 25 records, we may only get back 15 parent records if a certain portion of those parent records have multiple child records.

Typical Example:

```
SELECT C.Name, U.Make 
FROM Contacts C 
LEFT JOIN Units U on U.ContactId = C.ContactId 
OFFSET 10 FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Potential return values:

```
 Name  | Make
 Tommy | Toyota
 Tommy | Nissan
 Bob   | Chevy
 Bob   | Ford
 Christie | Chevy
```

As one can see, we are only getting back 3 parent records even though the total record set is the requested 5 items.

Is there a method of constructing the queries such that OFFSET and FETCH NEXT only apply to the parent table/records without brute forcing this by simply getting only the parent records and the running queries to populate our child properties?

Brute Force Example:

`var contacts = queryToGetParentRecords();
 foreach(var contact in contacts){
    contact.CarMakes = queryToGetChildData(contact.Id);
}`

Comment: Not within a single query, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ORDER BY in your SQL to make use of the FETCH, since there is no order to a SQL table.

I would use a window function for your purpose. If you are ordering by ContactId something like the following. You need to use a CTE or subquery to make use of the dense_rank results:

```
;with cte as (

    SELECT 
         C.Name, U.Make 
        ,dense_rank() over (order by C.ContactId) FetchRank
        FROM Contacts C 
        LEFT JOIN Units U
        ON U.ContactId = C.ContactId 

)
select Name, Make
    from cte
    where FetchRank between 10 and 15
```